# Why does bluetooth stop working when it detects a metered connection?

Tags: networking, windows-10, bluetooth

I am a bit surprised by the behavior of  Bluetooth functionality. Of late I made one of my Ethernet adapters to be a metered connection in order to save bandwidth usage, when I try to send files via bluetooth it is stuck for several minutes and won't send the files.

[image]

Is bluetooth functionality related to how the Ethernet adapter works, also what causes the metering of network adapters to stop bluetooth functionality?

*(Windows 10 Education, Realtek LAN adapter, Qualcomm Bluetooth adapter)*

Comment: Did you test whenever it doesn't happen if you don't have a metered connection? Do you just wait some time and it progresses or does it fail?

Comment: Yes I tested both ways, unless I either disable the LAN adapter or remove it from metering, it simply won't send, it never progresses. So to send files I temporarily disable LAN, because I want it to be metered. Alternatively I don't use bluetooth, I sent via Wi-Fi

Comment: @Seth I am a bit curious why this happens, because I thought they were not linked in terms of functionality, by the way thanks for replying